# Aligning object that has been reoriented in edit mode

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I have a simple object (say, a cylinder) that has been reoriented in edit mode from its default orientation.  Thus, whenever I try to snap the object to another object's face in object mode, the result always carries with it the unwanted reorientation and I never get a true normal alignment.  Is there a way to realign that object back to the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select a face of your cylinder, in the *Transform Orientations* panel, click on the "+" to create a custom orientation, that will be aligned with this face normal:

[image]

Back to *Object* mode, in the *Options*, enable the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option:

[image]

Then *Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation* in order to align the local orientation to the custom one:

[image]

Disable the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset the rotation of the object, in the *Transform Orientations* panel select back the *Global* orientation.

**For 2.7** as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-q4H81OAjM) by Oby 1:

In *Edit* mode select the top face of your rotated object (here a cube), press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> to have a frontal view:

[image]

Back in *Object* mode, keep the same view, create a new object, for example a plane, in the left panel enable *Align to View*:

[image]

Parent the cube to the plane, reset the plane rotation (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>), the cube will follow:

[image]

Deparent the cube with *Clear and Keep Transformation* (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>):

[image]

Apply the rotation of the cube ((<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using 2.79, because the current version won't work with my display adapter.  I can use up to 2.90.1, but when I do, Blender adds a huge amount of 'collections' complexity, when I load my file.  Do you happen to know if that automatic addition of collections can be disabled during the load, so I can get on with 2.90.1?

Comment: I think 2.9 will convert your layers into collections, and I don't think you can avoid that. There was a way to fix your problem with 2.7, not as easy as in 3, the answer must be somewhere in blenderstackexchange, I'll try to find.

Comment: ok I've found a method that works for 2.7 as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-q4H81OAjM I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: Goodness, moonboots!  Such a detailed (and correct) answer.  Thanks again.  I'd resigned myself to figuring out how to in 2.79 myself in Blender's ever changing interface.  But you beat me to it.  Many thanks.

Comment: Huh, TIL "Align to Transform Orientation". It seems it was added in 2.83, don't know how I missed that.