# How to make Pivot rotate in the same direction as the object?

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-manipulator

When I rotate an object, the pivot point doesn't follow the direction of the object, which makes editing really bad. The pivot point always stays on the same axes, no matter if you rotate the object. In cinema 4D this does not happen. How to do this in blander?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've rotated your cylinder in *Object* mode and want to see its orientation, open the *Transform Orientations* panel and switch from *Global* to *Local*:

[image]

If you've rotated the cylinder in *Edit* mode you need to realign the local axis correctly, see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/284897/aligning-object-that-has-been-reoriented-in-edit-mode/284907#284907).

Comment: Thanks very much!!!!!! Save me